# Pause game on orientation change, objective-c / Sprite Kit

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I want my game to pause when device orientation is initiated. I have this method in my viewcontroller, which works fine:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
NSLog(@"I am starting to rotate, should pause game..");
```

}

But how to listen for device rotation from within my SKScene, where the actual game is playing. Hope I have made myself clear enough. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you tried using the same code in your SKScene?

Comment: Yes, willRotate... doesn't get fired upon orientation change..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `NSNotification`. Keeping with your code, add the following line in your ViewController init:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
    postNotificationName:@"RotateNotification" 
                  object:self];
```

Then in your SKScene init add this line:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
    selector:@selector(receiveNotification:) 
        name:@"RotateNotification"
      object:nil];
```

Also add the called method to SKScene:

```
-(void) receiveNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSLog (@"Received notification");
    // do what you have to do here...
}
```